# Freely positioning text inside a UILabel programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uilabel

I have created a subclass of UILabel to change the alignment/position of the text inside my UILabels but the text is always top aligned. I read lot of topics but I didn't find someone this the same problem has mine.

It looks like the y origin in drawText func of my subclass is ignored when I call `super.drawText(in: r)`. I say that because origin.x, size.width and size.height of the rect I send to super.drawText() work as expected

Screenshot of the [result I currently get with the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VoWc.png)

Screenshot of [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYljH.png)

This is my UILabel subclass :

```
class Label : UILabel {

    enum VerticalAlignment {
        case top
        case middle
        case bottom
    }

    enum HorizontalAlignment {
        case left
        case center
        case right
    }

    var verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment = .middle {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    var horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    override public func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
        var rect: CGRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: limitedToNumberOfLines)

        rect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)

        switch verticalAlignment {
            case .top:
                break
            case .middle:
                rect.origin.y += ((bounds.size.height - rect.size.height) / 2.0)
            case .bottom:
                rect.origin.y += (bounds.size.height - rect.size.height)
        }
        switch horizontalAlignment {
            case .left:
                break
            case .center:
                rect.origin.x += ((bounds.size.width - rect.size.width) / 2.0)
            case .right:
                rect.origin.x += (bounds.size.width - rect.size.width)
        }
        return rect
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let r = self.textRect(forBounds: rect, limitedToNumberOfLines: self.numberOfLines)
        super.drawText(in: r)
    }

}
```

How I created my label :

```
func addtestLabel() {
    var label: Label = Label()

    label.text = "NICE LABEL!"
    label.textColor = hexToUIColor(hex: "#ffffff")
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 35, y: self.view.bounds.size.height - 120, width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 70, height: 75)
    label.backgroundColor = hexToUIColor(hex: "#000000")
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Savu-Condensed", size: label.frame.size.height / 2.0)
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 1

    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine except for a single line.  When creating your label you cannot set

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

and

```
label.numberOfLines = 1
```

I don't know why it breaks but it is not logical to wrap lines when there is only one so maybe something does not trigger.

You could either make the number of lines 0 or a number greater than 1. Another option is to delete the .byWordWrapping.  Either of these things will give you the result you are expecting.